# Python Merge line with 1 entry with next line

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, merge

With output like...

```
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
['AAA']
['BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
```

I want to merge the single element AAA with the next line BBB CCC DDD to form:
AAA BBB CCC DDD.

My current code is

```
   for s in my_input_string.split('\n'):
       s = ' '.join(s.split())
       entries = s.split(" ")

          if len(entries) < 2:
              print entries
          else:
              print entries[2]
```

And all it does is to return the correct output until the exception, where it first returns the single element, then a wrong entry, and then printing the wanted output yet again.

Comment: Entries represents one line, or a list of lists? We need more code than that.

Comment: That's trivial for static input. How would variable input look like? What rule do you want to implement?

Comment: That's how I see the output. Each line is read with a \n to signify the end of that line. Added the extra bits to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want

```
l = [['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD'],['AAA'],['BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD'],['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD'],['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    if(len(l[i]) < 2):
        l[i] = l[i] + l[i+1]
print l
```

You need to concatenate with the next list if it is length is <2

Comment: This then repeats the line twice, which is not what he wanted.